# Darle una función a un icono en KivyMD

Tags: python, python-3.7, kivy, icons, textfield

Quiero darle una función a un icono ingresado en un TextField, quiero darle la típica función que tiene el icono eye-off de las contraseñas que cuando aprete el icono cambie la función 'password' a False y si lo vuelvo a apretar pase a True, me explico, este es mi main code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton, MDIconButton
from kivy.lang import Builder
from helpers import *



class DemoApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Yellow'
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'

        btn = MDRectangleFlatButton(text='Confirmar', pos_hint= {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.35},
                                    on_release= self.show_data)

        self.username = Builder.load_string(username_helper)
        self.contraseña = Builder.load_string(contraseña_helper)

        screen.add_widget(self.username)
        screen.add_widget(self.contraseña)
        screen.add_widget(btn)
        return screen

    def show_data(self, obj):
        print(f'Usuario: {self.username.text}\nContraseña: {self.contraseña.text}')

if __name__=='__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

y aquí tengo mis archivos en modo string que es el modulo helpers que importé:

```
username_helper = '''
MDTextField:
    hint_text: 'Usuario'
    required: True
    helper_text: 'Enter text'
    helper_text_mode: 'on_error'
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    size_hint_x: None
    width: 200
'''

contraseña_helper = '''
MDTextField:
    hint_text: 'Contraseña'
    password: True
    icon_right: "eye-off"
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.43}
    size_hint_x: None
    width: 200
'''
```

con esta configuración, al escribir en contraseña algún string me aparece en con los asteriscos, pero quiero que al apretar el icono de 'eye-off' que se encuentra a la derecha pueda ver el string que estoy escribiendo, y si lo vuelvo a apretar se oculte de nuevo con las '*' y así sucesivamente.